# How to extend datatables sorting functions for multi rows levels support

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the next table structure:

[Table structure image](http://postimage.org/image/bq53yh8q1/)

As you can see there is some levels (3) in this table. I want to sort this table by levels:

1. Sort first levels (PC and Mobile phones)
2. Inside first levels sort second levels (resolutions)
3. Inside seond levels sort third levels (os name) etc.

I am forming this table from three objects (object['0']['data'], object['1']['data'] and object['2']['data']).

I used my own js library for this before, but now need switch to datatables.

Old code was like this

```
//Sort Level 1
    table_data.sort( sorter )

    // Sort Level 2
    for (var i in table_data) {

        table_data[i].data.sort( sorter );

        // Sort Level 3
        for (var j in table_data[i].data) {
            table_data[i].data[j].data.sort( sorter );
        }
    }
```

How to implement this using datatables plugin?

Comment: If you hold alt you can sort more than one column at a time right? Isn't that the same as sorting multiple levels? If you do need a tree, you could also open the row on datatables using fnOpen() and you could put another table inside, thus creating levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort this data using datable is incorrect, because it is not actually a table - this is tree decorated as a table, so better to use your own js library for sort tree (or with angularjs it is very easy to make). But if you still want to use datatable - need to sort aoData object, which contains current datatable data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the Grouping with [DataTables - Row Grouping](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

and the sorting of the group column using fnSort(),
See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRJF/2/) on JSFiddle.